# python list + empty numpy array = empty numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Today I noticed something odd in my code, and discovered that in certain situations it run down to the execution of the following:

```
my_list = [0] + np.array([])
```

which results in `my_list` being the following:

```
array([], dtype=float64)
```

At the beginning I was quite confused, than I understood that the interpreter is first converting the list to a numpy array, and then trying a broadcasting operation:

```
>>> np.array([0]) + np.array([])
array([], dtype=float64)
```

I have some questions about this behaviour:

- Why is it broadcasting?
- Wouldn't it be better if python threw an
  error, at least for this particular case where a list is converted and made
  disappear?

Thank you for your clarifications!

Comment: This seems to be a specific choice of ``numpy`` for shapes ``(1,)`` + ``(0,)``. For example, ``np.array([0, 3]) + np.array([])`` is an error.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is broadcasting because that is what ``+`` means for ``numpy``. It is not an error because the result is defined as ``array([])``.

Comment: Broadcasting to 0 is consistent with the documented rules. We just don't see it often, and are surprised.

Comment: If it's fully answered by the documentation then I think that is enough to constitute an answer by pointing to the relevant parts. Or, there may be a dupe. I'm not sure why this is voted to be closed, though, because I am certainly surprised by seeing numpy rules play out like this. If it's the result of documented behaviour then I fail to see how it's opinion-based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all:

> Wouldn't it be better if python threw an error, at least for this particular case where a list is converted and made disappear?

I don't think that test is possible. According [to this comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/79d23f0bdc6a5e6bcd280cd93f73fabca8e2469f/numpy/core/src/common/binop_override.h#L68):

> For reversed operations like `b.__radd__(a)` we call the corresponding ufunc.

This means that using `[0] + np.array([])` will actually call the ufunc `np.add([0], np.array([]))`, which converts array-like lists to arrays without having a chance to decide about the size of the operands.

So broadcasting is a given. The question is then whether it's sane to have shapes `(1,)` and `(0,)` broadcast to `(0,)`. You can think about it this way: scalars always broadcast, and 1-element 1d arrays are as good as scalars in most situations:

```
>>> np.add([0], [])
array([], dtype=float64)

>>> np.add(0, [])
array([], dtype=float64)
```

If you look at it this way it makes sense as a rule, even though I agree it's surprising, especially that non-one-length arrays won't broadcast like this. But it's not a bug (just an interesting situation for a feature).

---

To be more precise, what is happening with broadcasting is always that "dimensions with size 1 will broadcast". The array-like `[0]` has shape `(1,)`, and the `np.array([])` has shape `(0,)` (as opposed to a scalar `np.int64()` which would have shape `()`!). So broadcasting happens on the singleton, and the result has shape `(0,)`.

It gets clearer if we inject more singleton dimensions:

```
>>> ([0] + np.array([])).shape
(0,)

>>> ([[0]] + np.array([])).shape
(1, 0)

>>> ([[[0]]] + np.array([])).shape
(1, 1, 0)

>>> np.shape([[[0]]])
(1, 1, 1)
```

So for instance in the last case shapes `(1, 1, 1)` will nicely broadcast with a 1d array along its last dimension, and the result should indeed be `(1, 1, 0)` in this case.